# What do you need to learn OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

What do you need to learn OpenGL? Do you need to learn C/C++ first? I have experience with C but none with C++.

Comment: If you need to ask, then you don't need to learn it as simple as that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a good book for learning OpenGL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540/whats-a-good-book-for-learning-opengl)

Comment: There's no need to learn C++ in order to use it. The API is specified for C (and therefore usable by C++), and there are bindings for [several other languages](http://www.opengl.org/resources/bindings/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using c++ due to it having an object oriented side, but the opengl is cross platform 
http://www.opengl.org/resources/bindings/

Comment: C++ has classes, but that doesn't make it object oriented. You can do object oriented programming in C just fine (and IMHO even much closer to what OOP is about, than in C++).

Answer (score 0):

You can use mostly C with very little C++.

I would suggest looking at nehe.gamedev.net for some tutorials to help out.

Comment: Depends on how up-to-date the asker wants to be.  A lot of the stuff NeHe uses is now deprecated.

Comment: True, but a lot of the "older" stuff is just a super set of later APIs. I agree consulting the Red Book will be helpful, but a lot of people also compile to older version of OGL.

Comment: @nmjohn: No, most of the older stuff got completely removed from later versions of OpenGL. Matrix Stack: Gone. Fixed Function Pipeline: Gone. Immediate Mode: Gone. Texture Environment: Gone.